# sizeof reference differing for class type and data member

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
double &num1;
public:
Test(double &num2):num1(num2)
    {
        cout<<sizeof(num1);//Prints 8
    }
};

 int main()
{
    double num1=10;
    Test t(num1);
    cout<<sizeof(t);//Prints 4
    return 0;
}
```

Why sizeof() is giving this result when printed for data members and when printed for object?

Comment: What else did you expect?

Comment: Let me guess, you're compiling for a 32bit system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1` is a reference, so `sizeof(num1)` gives the size of the object referred to - here a `double`.

`sizeof(T)` returns the size of the class, not the size of any objects the class members might refer to. In this case the class size might reflect the fact that the reference is implemented as a 32-bit address of the `double`. This is an implementation detail that the language doesn't say anything about.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(t)` is `sizeof(Test)` is the size of a `double&` plus any padding. On your system, apparently, stored references take up 4 bytes and there is no padding in use for this type.

`sizeof(num1)` is `sizeof(double)` because that's what happens when you name a reference: you actually refer to the referred-to object instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the size of the referenced type when it is applied to a reference. This means in the first case it returns `sizeof(double)`. In the second case, it returns the size of your class, which only stores a reference.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

> When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.

`sizeof(num1)` is `sizeof(double)`.

but

`sizeof (Test)` is the place which is require to store reference which might be equivalent to `sizeof (double*)` in your case.

Comment: Is it actually stated anywhere that the "size of" a reference type is always equal to that of the equivalent pointer type? You're also avoiding the issue of padding/alignment (in the general case).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I dislike also how I word that part. I tried to improve it.

Comment: I was asking genuinely :)

Answer (score 1):

Your class is just storing a reference - therefore the compiler knows that 4 bytes is sufficient